# Showing Segmentation Fault when Attempting to Reverse a Linked List

Tags: c++, reverse, singly-linked-list

I tried reversing a section of a singly Linked list using this code.

Here startOfSec is the pointer at the starting node of the section of the linked list which is to be reversed, and endofSec is the pointer to the last node of that section.

Now, with this code, I'm getting segmentation fault but if I replace endOfSec->next with NULL (I'm changing the value of the pointer, pointing to the last node of the section(which is to be reversed) of the original linked list, to NULL as well) in the while loop condition, it works perfectly!

```
void reverseList(ListNode* startOfSec, ListNode *endOfSec){

    ListNode *prev = NULL;
    ListNode *curr = startOfSec;
    ListNode *nxt;
    while(curr!=endOfSec->next){
        nxt = curr->next;
        curr->next = prev;
        prev = curr;
        curr = nxt;
    }
}

Callsite:
//code to get start and end pointers
reverseList(start, end);
```

I expected my code to reverse the section of the list without the need of setting end->next pointer as NULL.

Comment: What is `endOfSec`? Where does it point? Can you please try to create a [mcve] to show us?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `endOfSec` points to the last node of the section of list  which I want to get reversed. For instance if the list is `1->2->3->4->5->6->7->8`  and the section to be reversed is `3->4->5->6` then startOfSec points to 3 and endOfSec points to 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with this code, some easier to fix than others. For this specific segmentation fault, a code walkthrough reveals the cause. Let's look at what happens with a simple example. (You should learn how to do this on your own, either by hand or using a debugger.)

```
start -> end -> NULL
```

This is a list with two elements, one named "start" and the other "end". Meh, let's say "start" and "end" are also pointers to the nodes. It's a little ambiguous, but it should not cause problems this time. Now reverse the list.

```
reverseList(start, end);
```

Before the first iteration of the loop in `reverseList` (i.e. after the initializations), your data looks like the following.

```
startOfSec == start
endOfSec == end;     endOfSec->next == NULL;
prev == NULL
curr == start
nxt == /* uninitialized */

start -> end -> NULL
```

After the first iteration, the data has been updated.

```
startOfSec == start
endOfSec == end;     endOfSec->next == NULL;
prev == start
curr == end
nxt == end

start -> NULL
end -> NULL
```

After the second iteration, the data has been updated.

```
startOfSec == start
endOfSec == end;     endOfSec->next == start;
prev == end
curr == NULL
nxt == NULL

end -> start -> NULL
```

Congrats, the list has been reversed. Now all we have to do is exit the loop, so we would like `curr` to equal `endOfSec->next`. However, `NULL` is not equal to `start`, so we continue into a third iteration, and crash when we try to read `curr->next` (a.k.a. `NULL->next`).

Overall, you need to revise how you track the beginning and end of the section to reverse. The current crash comes about because you lose track of the end of the section. (Maybe check `prev != endOfSec` instead?) You will also have a problem if the end of the section is not the end of the list (the part of the list after the reversed section will be lost in limbo), but that is easy to fix by changing how `prev` is initialized. The biggest problem I see is when the *beginning* of the section is not the beginning of the list – changing a singly-linked list requires modifications to the node before the change (a.k.a. the node before `startOfSec`).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and efforts you've put on framing the answer! I realized it's a pity to ask a question like this and that I should've put more efforts in debugging. I'll remember this next time. In response to your concern regarding the nodes before and after the section, I'd like to add that a part of code before the call site kept variables for the nodes before as well as after the section (which was to be reversed) and changed their connectivity with the section accordingly outside the function.